# Artifactory: How to sort by date modified in the native browser view?

Tags: sorting, artifactory

How can sort by date modified when you launch the Native Browser view from UI:
[image]

Access the native browser view from Artifactory UI and sort by date modified to make it easier for Developers to download latest builds.

Comment: good question. in my case we'd need "numeric sorting" in the artifactory "native browser".

Answer (score 1):

This bothered me enough to write a quick injection script to provide the functionality.

So a workaround if you *really, really* want sorting:

1. Use a browser extension that allows you to inject custom JS + CSS into pages, e.g. [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld) for Chrome
2. Add a JS + CSS injection for your Artifactory base URL with the script below.
3. Profit, you can now sort by name, modified and even size on every page of the "native ui" by clicking the arrows:

[image: An image showing the jfrog Artifactory UI with sorting options added]

```js
const convertDate = (dateStr = "") => {
    if (!dateStr?.trim()) return null;
    const year = 2000 + parseInt(dateStr.substring(6, 8)); // won't deal with years before 2000 for obvious reasons
    const month = parseInt(dateStr.substring(3, 5))-1;
    const day = parseInt(dateStr.substring(0, 2));
    const hours = parseInt(dateStr.substring(9, 11));
    const minutes = parseInt(dateStr.substring(12, 14));
    const seconds = parseInt(dateStr.substring(15, 17));
    const offset = parseInt(dateStr.substring(19, 21));
    const addOffset = dateStr.substring(18, 19) === "+";

    const date = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + (addOffset ? -offset : offset));
    
    return date;
};

const compareNames = (a, b, inverse = false) => {
    let name1 = a.children[0].innerText?.trim();
    let name2 = b.children[0].innerText?.trim();
    if (!name1 || name1.indexOf("..") === 0) return -1;
    if (!name2 || name2.indexOf("..") === 0) return 1;
    
    if (inverse) {
        const tmp = name1;
        name1 = name2;
        name2 = tmp;
    }
    
    return name1 < name2 ? -1 : 1;
};

const compareDates = (a, b, inverse = false) => {
    let date1 = convertDate(a.children[1].innerText?.trim());
    let date2 = convertDate(b.children[1].innerText?.trim());
    if (!date1) return -1;
    if (!date2) return 1;
    
    if (inverse) {
        const tmp = date1;
        date1 = date2;
        date2 = tmp;
    }
    
    return date1.getTime() > date2.getTime() ? -1 : 1;
};

const SIZE_MULT = {
    "B" : 1,
    "KB": 10 ** 3,
    "MB": 10 ** 6,
    "GB": 10 ** 9,
    "TB": 10 ** 12,
    "PB": 10 ** 15
};

const getSizeInBytes = (str) => {
    const lastSpace = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
    if (!lastSpace) return -1;
    const sizePart = parseFloat(str.substring(0, lastSpace));
    if (isNaN(sizePart)) return -1;
    const multiplier = SIZE_MULT[str.substring(lastSpace+1)];
    if (!multiplier) return -1;
    return sizePart * multiplier;
};

const compareSize = (a, b, inverse = false) => {
    let size1 = a.children[2].innerText?.trim();
    let size2 = b.children[2].innerText?.trim();
    if (!size1 && !size2) return compareNames(a, b);
    if (!size1) return -1;
    if (!size2) return 1;
    
    if (inverse) {
        const tmp = size1;
        size1 = size2;
        size2 = tmp;
    }
    
    const s1 = getSizeInBytes(size1);
    const s2 = getSizeInBytes(size2);
    return s1 < s2 ? -1 : 1;
};

const sorter = (container, comparator = compareNames) => {
    const children = [...container.children];
    
    for (const child of children) {
        child.remove();
    }

    children.sort(comparator);
    
    for (const child of children) {
        container.appendChild(child);
    }
};

const TRIANGLE_FILLED_UP = "▲";
const TRIANGLE_FILLED_DOWN = "▼";
const TRIANGLE_UP = "△";
const TRIANGLE_DOWN = "▽";

const sortedColumnsConfig = {
    "name": compareNames,
    "last modified": compareDates,
    "size": compareSize
};

let currentCol = null;
let currentSortDirectionDefault = null;
const all_buttons = [];

const resetButtons = (buttons) => {
    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.innerText = TRIANGLE_UP;
    }); 
};

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("Checking for native artifacts table...");
    const table = document.querySelector(".native-browser .table[data-cy='artifacts-table']");
    if (!table) return;
    
    console.log("Found native artifacts table! Injecting sorter functions");
    clearInterval(interval);
    
    const header = table.querySelector(".table-columns.table-header");
    const rows = table.querySelector(".table-rows");
    if (!header || !rows) throw new Error("UI loaded but rows could not be found!");
    
    const columns = Array.from(header.children);
    for (const columnName of Object.keys(sortedColumnsConfig)) {
        const column = columns.find(col => col.innerText?.toLowerCase() === columnName);
        if (!column) throw new Error(`Could not find column name '${columnName}'!`);
        
        const columnSorter = sortedColumnsConfig[columnName];
        
        const sorterButton = document.createElement("button");
        sorterButton.classList.add("arrow-btn");
        sorterButton.innerText = TRIANGLE_UP;
        all_buttons.push(sorterButton);
        
        sorterButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const sortInverted = currentCol === columnName && currentSortDirectionDefault;
            currentCol = columnName;
            currentSortDirectionDefault = !sortInverted;
            
            resetButtons(all_buttons);
            sorter(rows, (a, b) => columnSorter(a, b, sortInverted));
            sorterButton.innerText = sortInverted ? TRIANGLE_FILLED_UP : TRIANGLE_FILLED_DOWN;
            
            console.log(`Successfully completed sort for column '${columnName}' (inverted: ${sortInverted})`);
        });
        
        column.appendChild(sorterButton);
    }
    
    console.log("Sorting injected!");
}, 500);
```

And css:

```css
.arrow-btn {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestions! will try for sure...

Comment: great stuff, works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory native browser does not support column sorting at the moment.
The native browser view maintains the original tree view structure of the Artifacts tree browser, which is sorted by Name.

Alternately, you can use an AQL (Artifactory Query Language) to fetch the artifacts by created/modified ascending/descending order:

```
curl -u<username>:<password> -XPOST "http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/search/aql" -d 'items.find({"repo": "repo"}).sort({"$desc": ["modified"]})'  -H "Content-Type: text/plain"
```

For additional information, please refer to the AQL API documentation
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-ComparisonOperators

Comment: Can we submit this as a future request then. Bummer. Thanks for your reply !

Comment: You surely can :)

Comment: @AK2116 Feel free to accept this answer If it satisfies your needs at the moment